# Scraping all markers from iframe with Python and Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, iframe

I'm trying to scrape the company name and link from the map embedded in this web: https://www.elitedynamics.co.uk/customers

The code I've developed since now enters the page, scrolls down until finding the first button (every marker is a button). And then clicks the button, the information in shown and selected, the button is closed and the driver goes to the next result. It's very chaotic because the driver is not able to follow an order and repeats elements. Is there a better way to do it?

```
driver_path='chromedriver'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path,options = chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.elitedynamics.co.uk/customers")
property_bubble = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="button"]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(property_bubble).click(property_bubble).perform()
all_properties = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="button"]')
names_list =[]
links_list=[]

for property in all_properties:
    actions.move_to_element(property).click(property).perform()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'wpgmza_infowindow_description')))
    property_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="wpgmza_infowindow_description"]/h4')
    names_list.append(property_name.text)
    print(property_name)
    try:
        property_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="wpgmza_infowindow_description"]/h4/a')
        links_list.append(property_link.get_attribute('href'))
        print(property_link)
    except:
        try:
            property_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="wpgmza_infowindow_description"]/h4/p/a')
            links_list.append(property_link.get_attribute('href'))  
            print(property_link)
        except:
            pass    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@title="Close"]').click()
print(names_list)
print(links_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to scrape the site ,you don't need to use selenium because required data is pretty much generating from external source as json.

Here is the working solution:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'filter': '{"map_id":"4","mashupIDs":[],"customFields":[]}'
    
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        elit = []
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        for item in r.json()['markers']:
            elit.append([item['title'], item['icon']['url']])

        df = pd.DataFrame(elit, columns=["Title", "Url"])
        print(df)


main(
    'https://www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-json/wpgmza/v1/features/')
```

OUTPUT:

```
                    Title                                                Url
0              Landal Darwin Forest  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
1                 Landal Sandybrook  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
2             Pinewood Holiday Park  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
3           Peppermint Holiday Park  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
4          Riviera Bay Holiday Park  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
..                              ...                                                ...  
250        Hedley Wood Holiday Park  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
251  Ashbourne Heights Holiday Park  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
252    Sand le Mere Holiday Village  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
253                    Bowland Fell  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  
254       Silver Sands Holiday Park  //www.elitedynamics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2...  

[255 rows x 2 columns]
```